# jQuery script to show data-message

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using jQuery validator() to display HTML form 'data-message' if the field is invalid. Is there a way call the data-message on command?

For example, instead of my JS throwing an alert with

```
alert("Wrong file!");
```

I would like to instead show the `data-message` from the HTML form.

Here's my form input file field:

```
<input type="file" name="orders_csv" id="orders_csv"  required="required" data-message="Please attach the morders.csv file.">
```

And here's my current JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#upload-form").validator({
        position: 'top center',
        offset: [-12, 40],
        relative: true,
        accept: "csv",
        message: '<div><em></em></div>'
    })
    // make sure that mcust.csv is the attached file. If not, throw alert message
    $("input#dealers_csv").on("change", function() {
        $('#loader').hide();
        var dealers = $("input#dealers_csv");
        var arrfilepath = dealers.val().split("\\");
        var filename = arrfilepath[arrfilepath.length - 1];
        if (filename != "mcust.csv") {
            alert($("#dealers_csv").data("message"));
            dealers.val('');
        }
    });
    // make sure that morders.csv is the attached file. If not, throw alert message
    $("input#orders_csv").on("change", function() {
        $('#loader').hide();
        var orders = $("input#orders_csv");
        var arrfilepath2 = orders.val().split("\\");
        var filename2 = arrfilepath2[arrfilepath2.length - 1];
        if (filename2 != "morders.csv") {
            alert($("#orders_csv").data("message"));
            orders.val('');
        }
    });
```

Comment: See added code in question above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will grab the form element's data-message attribute:

```
$("#orders_csv").data("message")
```

It works with jQuery 1.43 and above. See the jQuery docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5). Put this in whatever response mechanism you have for your validation (alert, jQuery UI popup, etc.).

You're using jQuery Tools for validation, it seems. To do what you want, to get the right tooltip to appear, you need to actually add a validation routine to the validator. Here's how I believe it should go:

```
$.tools.validator.fn("#dealers_csv, #orders_csv", function(element, value) {
    var correctFilename = (element.attr("id") === "dealers_csv" ? "mcust.csv" : "morders.csv"),
        $element = $(element),
        filename = value.split("\\").pop();
    if (filename !== correctFilename) {
        return $element.attr("data-message");
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Add this validation routine after your call to `$("#upload-form").validator()`. And remove most of the `.change()` event handlers, leaving only the following:

```
$("input#dealers_csv, input#orders_csv").on("change", function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
});
```

Here's the complete code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#upload-form").validator({
        position: 'top center',
        offset: [-12, 40],
        relative: true,
        accept: "csv",
        message: '<div><em></em></div>'
    });
    // the custom validation routine, checking only those elements with the ids in the selector
    $.tools.validator.fn("#dealers_csv, #orders_csv", function(element, value) {
        var correctFilename = (element.attr("id") === "dealers_csv" ? "mcust.csv" : "morders.csv"),
            $element = $(element),
            filename = value.split("\\").pop();
        if (filename !== correctFilename) {
            return $element.attr("data-message");
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
    // new, simplified event handler, to clear the "#loader" element when there's a change to the upload inputs
    $("#dealers_csv, #orders_csv").on("change", function() {
        $('#loader').hide();
    });
});
```

Principle difference between this code and your original is that, when failing validation for the upload inputs, it doesn't clear the value in them; your previous version did. I thought that clearing the input was kind of antithetical to validation, and felt wrong placing it in the validation routine.

Comment: It was just a placeholder for whatever selector would "grab" your form element. I've now updated with the appropriate call for your form element, with the id `orders_csv`.

Comment: This grabs the text from the data-message and shows it in an alert. I want to instead display the jQuery validation tool-tip that shows hovering over the form field.

Comment: Or $(this).data("message") could be used inside the alert.

Comment: @Sheikh, you're right, if used for the event callbacks, `$(this).data("message")` is not only an alternative, it's the better choice.

Comment: Thanks, is this same as $(this).attr("data-message"), I'm not aware of this.

Comment: @Sheikh For accessing the data attribute, yes, they're similar. For setting the data attribute, they don't function identically.

Comment: @adamdehaven, what's the documentation link to the `validator` plugin?

Comment: @PaulB.
I'm kind of a newby to JS and jQuery... what do you mean? I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but I am using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: @adamdehaven no, I was looking for the documentation for the validation plugin you are using. Seems as though you're using jQuery Tools. If so, you need to write custom validation routines, rather than doing the validation in your `change` event handler. I'm putting the changed code in the revised version of this answer.

Comment: @adamdehaven It's there now. :) Replace most of your `.change` event handlers with this.

Comment: @PaulB. Can you edit your above code to show me exactly what I should have based on the code at the top of the page? I'm not sure what to leave and what to take out...?

Comment: @adamdehaven Done; should be pretty self-explanatory, though, if not, say so.

Comment: @PaulB. Ok that looks great EXCEPT one things: (1.) Can you edit the code so that when they attach the CORRECT file, the tooltip message automatically goes away immediately even before clicking Submit?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8800/discussion-between-paul-b-and-adamdehaven)

Answer (score 1):

Replace your each

```
alert("...");
```

with

```
alert($(this).attr("data-message"));
```

Comment: This is doing the same thing as the answer by @Paul B.
I don't want to show the message in a pop-up alert. I want to show the jQuery validation error that hovers above the field as shown in this: http://justpaste.it/alert-fiddle

Answer (score 0):

If your file inputs are part of the upload-form you can trigger validation on the change event instead of the keyup event by doing this:

```
$("#upload-form").validator({
    errorInputEvent: 'change',
    position: 'top center',
    offset: [-12, 40],
    relative: true,
    accept: "csv",
    message: '<div><em></em></div>'
});
```

How to trigger an error if the file does not match a certain filename is probably harder to do, but here is a lot of [documentation](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/validator/index.html) for that plugin, start reading it and see if you find something there?